# How to convert multiple .XLSX files in a diretory to CSV using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to convert the `.xlsx` files of a folder into `CSV` using pandas, but I get the following error:

Code:

```py
import os
import pandas as pd

path = os.path.join(r'C:\Users\Sandy Gomes\Desktop\folder1\*.xlsx')
files = os.listdir(path)
```

Error:

```
OSError Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\JUNGLE~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_1692/3413042739.py in <module>
      1 path = os.path.join(r'C:\Users\Sandy Gomes\Desktop\folder1\*.xlsx')
----> 2 files = os.listdir(path)

OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'C:\\Users\\Sandy Gomes\\Desktop\\folder1\\*.xlsx'
```

Can you help me?

Comment: `*` is not a valid filename.

Comment: you are mixing 2 things. the expression with *.xlsx can be used with `glob.glob()`. For `os.listdir()` you need to pass a folder `os.listdir('C:\Users\Sandy Gomes\Desktop\folder1')`. Be careful, listdir just gives you a list of the files in a folder, not their path. If you want to have a list of the path of all xlsx files, use `glob.glob("C:\Users\Sandy Gomes\Desktop\folder1\*.xlsx")`. Final note, I suggest you change `\ ` in `/` in the path as it may create issue with things like `\n`

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to get a list of all xlsx file in folder1:

```
import os
import glob

os.chdir(r"C:\Users\Sandy Gomes\Desktop\folder1") #Change directory to folder1
filenames = glob.glob("*.xlsx") #List of filenames

print(filenames)
```

OR

```
path = (r"C:\Users\Sandy Gomes\Desktop\folder1\")
filenames = glob.glob(path + "*.xlsx")

print(filenames)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get all the files from the folder is to use `pathlib`:

```
from pathlib import Path
# Path.cwd() get the current working directory - this can be replaced with any directory
# .glob gets all the files of the specified type
# **/*.xlsx recursively searches all the folders for the given file type
files = list(Path(Path.cwd()).glob("**/*.xlsx"))
```

[Here is an example](https://dev.to/abbazs/how-to-add-folders-to-python-module-search-path-11af) of using `pathlib` set python modules search paths